# Does 2D time dependent Schrödinger equation example work?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I have entered the example: www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/solve-a-wave-equation-in-2d.html

into 12.0, and gotten an error message in the uifWave assignment.  It says, "incomplete expression; more input is needed".  I have hand entered the statement from the web since I don't know how to get a copy from the screen--but I believe that I have done it accurately.

Has anyone made this example work?  If so, I must have made some error--and would appreciate learning how to copy the text from the screen properly.  Otherwise, could someone clarify how to make the example work?

Answer (score 7):

Click on each input of [`code`](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/solve-a-wave-equation-in-2d.html) and a window will open that contains copy and paste-able code. After copy and paste of each code block into a workbook, select all workbook cells and convert them to `Raw InputForm` (Cell | Convert To | Raw InputForm) which can then be copy and pasted to this site. The code is then

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Ω = RegionDifference[RegionUnion[
     Disk[], Rectangle[{0, 0}, 
      {2, 2}]], Disk[{1/4, 1/4}, 
     1/5]]; 

uifWave = Quiet[NDSolveValue[
     {D[u[t, x, y], t, t] - 
        Inactive[Laplacian][
         u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
      u[0, x, y] == 
       E^(-5*((x - 3/2)^2 + 
          (y - 3/2)^2)), 
      Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, 
        y] == 0, DirichletCondition[
       u[t, x, y] == 0, True]}, u, 
     {t, 0, 2*Pi}, Element[{x, y}, 
      Ω]]]; 

framesWEQ = Table[Plot3D[
     uifWave[t, x, y], 
     Element[{x, y}, uifWave[
       "ElementMesh"]], 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
     Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
     Mesh -> None], {t, 0, 2*Pi, 
     2*(Pi/50)}]; 

Manipulate[framesWEQ[[i]], 
  {{i, 16, "time"}, 1, 
   Length[framesWEQ], 1}, 
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: OK.  It looks like the example was displayed in TraditionalForm, and when I manually copied it, that format omitted the Inactive directive in its presentation.  I will try the method mentioned to copy and transform the web presentation to Mathematica input form.